# What happens if I put wood sealant on top of wood finish by accident?

Tags: staining, refinishing, hardwood

Today we were supposed to do a second coat of finish on our hard wood floors. But accidentally we started with the sealant we used before we did our first coat of finish... we noticed about 25min in that it was the wrong stuff so we washed it off then tried wiping it up with a towel.

Now we don’t know if we messed it all up or if we can sand the part we put sealant on and just start with our second coat of finish?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what "sealant" and final finish you were using but there's a dirty secret in the finishing world, in general "sealant" products are nothing more than dilute forms of wood finish.

This isn't universal but presumably the two products you have there are similar enough that you couldn't immediately spot that you'd opened the wrong tin, which suggests that they are from the same 'family' so to speak. So you could unknowingly have been applying the very same thing as your final finish, just in more dilute form, sold in a different package.

If you managed to clean it off without making a mess of the surface and the area dries properly there's a good chance you can continue to apply your second coat of finish.

If you're concerned there might be an issue do a small test in an inconspicuous spot and see how it dries, whether it dries too slowly or incompletely, remaining sticky for an extended period, which would suggest an incompatibility.